# Access 2007 Visual Basic Code Subversioning

Tags: ms-access, tortoisesvn, vba

Is there a way to version the VBA modules inside an Access 2007 database, or am I just stuck with exporting the code and keeping it separate from the database and maintaining two different copies?

Comment: Assuming you have database split for client/server, the usual solution is to save a copy of the whole FE database with its code.  I realize the versioning paradigm is not really fulfilled.  I'm interested to see others' answers, and after all my experience stops with 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access has a MSSCCI interface which you can connect to any source control system which has a MSSCCI interface. Many of them do. For example for SVN there is AgentSVN or VisualSVN.

Download and install the Access 2007 Developer Extensions, and choose the source code control from your installed SCC providers.

Source control in MS Access uses the Access SaveAsText/LoadFromText methods. All recent versions of Access use a VBA object to hold the VBA modules in, they aren't stored natively in the database anymore, so you can't just export the record holding each module as you used to be able to do.

There are mixed reports about using integrated source control in MS Access. Your milage may vary.

On a historical note, a multi-user, multi-process relational database is ideal for ensuring coherance in source code. According to some reports, the Office 2000 developers were unable to maintain project coherence when using the native database to store modules, and fixed it by using a locked single project object. Possibly missing the fact that Windows 2000 SMB server was corrupting data (fixed in Win2K SP1).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the response so far, I conclude you can't have versioning.

I believe this is because an Access DB code-base is not viewed as a set of modules -- that is, not as interchangeable elements the way code is in many other settings.  A truly modular approach increases the requirement for strict control because you must ensure coherence; thus, versioning.

Code in VBA is not handled as agile -- which of course is understandable historically.  It's a huge watershed in development approach.  So while you benefit from an agile mindset, you won't find it facilitated so well.

### NOTE:

In case you're not aware, some key aspects of modular approach are met by separating the app into client and server documents (splitting your database).

Comment: Yeah, I ended up giving up on trying to make the code separate from the database.  Thanks for your feedback!